# Ecs agents restarting in non Amazon Linux Image

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos7, amazon-ecs

As we need to go with custom AMI for ECS, we have followed the steps mentioned in the documentation for non Amazon Linux EC2 Instance. The problem is after installing the ecs agent, the agent keeps on restarting and kills after some time and also no logs are written.We are using Cent Os 7 as the base AMI.
The following statements are below:

## docker run --name ecs-agent --detach=true --restart=on-failure:10 --volume=/var/run:/var/run --volume=/var/log/ecs/:/log --volume=/var/lib/ecs/data:/data --volume=/etc/ecs:/etc/ecs --net=host --env-file=/etc/ecs/ecs.config amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest

c135d49fd71fe2090c66fef35e53c742de4061adae29f5cc8a7f63a93ea48bc2

## docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                                  PORTS               NAMES
c135d49fd71f        amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest   "/agent"            4 seconds ago       *Restarting (1) Less than a second ago*                       ecs-agent

Comment: Have you made sure your EC2 has proper IAM role?. For ECS - `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role`.

Comment: Yeah thanks @Imran. That was the problem and it is resolved